# php product filtering and url parsing

Tags: php, url

I'm creating a sidebar which will include product filter based on item size, color price etc...

Using this function:

```
  function queryUrl()
  {
      $parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      $string = '';
      if (isset($parts['query'])) {
          $args = explode("&amp;", $parts['query']);
          foreach ($args as $arg) {
              $keyval = explode("=", $arg);
              $string .= "&amp;" . clean($keyval);
          }
      }
      return $string;
  }
```

Something like:

```
Color:
<a href="<?php echo queryUrl();?>?filter=true&color=green">Green</a>
<a href="<?php echo queryUrl();?>?filter=true&color=blue">Blue</a>

Size
<a href="<?php echo queryUrl();?>?filter=true&size=xxl">XXL</a>
<a href="<?php echo queryUrl();?>?filter=true&size=xl">XL</a>

...
```

My url is http://example.com/search/

The expected result is:

```
http://example.com/search/?filter=true&color=green&size=xxl
```

but instead I end up with repeated url string like:

```
http://example.com/search/?filter=true&color=green&size=xxl&filter=true&color=green&size=xxl
```

Each time I click on one of the links, everything get added to url.

The idea is if different color is selected, replace only color, keep everything else, if size is clicked replace only size, but keep everything else. The same goes for the price and other filtering options.